# KeyError, even though key is in dictionary? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

Ok, so I am getting a key error, and I've narrowed it down to this function here:

```
    def find_coexistance(D, query):
        '''(dict,str)->list
        Description: outputs locations of words in a test based on query
        Precondition: D is a dictionary and query is a string
        '''
        query = query.split(" ")

        if (len(query) == 1):
            return D[str(query)]
        else:
            return D.intersection(query)
##############################
# main
##############################
file=open_file()
d=read_file(file)
query=input("Enter one or more words separated by spaces, or 'q' to quit:").strip().lower()
a = find_coexistance(d, query)
print (a)
```

This is the following output I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hrith\Documents\ITI work\A5_300069290\a5_part1_300069290.py", 
line 135, in <module>
a = find_coexistance(d, query)
File "C:\Users\hrith\Documents\ITI work\A5_300069290\a5_part1_300069290.py", 
line 122, in find_coexistance
return D[str(query)]
KeyError: "['this']"
```

and this is what is inside the dictionary:

```
d = {'this': {1, 2, 3, 4}, 'is': {1, 2, 3, 4}, 'man': {1, 2}, 'also': {2, 
    4}, 'woman': {3, 4}}
```

and if I check if 'this' is in the dictionary, I get:

```
>>>'this' in d
True
```

So what am I doing wrong??????

Comment: Look at the error message more closely. The key that fails is `"['this']"`, not `'this'`.

Comment: `query = query.split(" ")` returns you a **list** of string, not a string. And your dict keys are not lists of strings, hence it isn't found. The standard idiom would be `query.split(" ")[0]`

Comment: Ok, I see but how else would access the key in the dicitionary. Isn't the syntax for accessing a dictionary: d[key]

Comment: Make sure you are trying to access the dict with a single string, not a list. `print(query)` before you try the access, if you want to check; but the error message is already telling you as much. EDIT: as @DYZ says, don't do `str(query)`, which will try to use a **string-representation-of-a-list-of-string**! Instead of an actual string(!)

Comment: You should use `D[query[0]]`, not `D[str(query)]`

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense. Feel really stupid right now. Thank you so much @smci

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Comment: We sorely need a canonical **"Why does Python `split()` always return a list, not a string/int/etc., and how can I handle that in code?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `split()` on a string, it *always* returns a list.  So `"foo bar".split(" ")` gives `["foo", "bar" ]`.  BUT `"foo".split(" ")` gives a 1-element list `["foo"]`.

The code is using a *list of strings* as the dictionary index, not a plain string.

```
def find_coexistance(D, query):
    query = query.split(" ")

    if (len(query) == 1):
        return D[str(query)]   # <-- HERE
    else:
        return D.intersection(query)
```

It's a simple fix, take the first element of the split.

```
def find_coexistance(D, query):
    query = query.split(" ")

    if (len(query) == 1):
        return D[query[0]]   # <-- HERE
    else:
        return D.intersection(query)
```

Comment: The `intersection` call is also problematic in the code, but maybe that's left out on purpose.

Comment: Yeah I left that for later. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `query.split(" ")` returns a list.  Using str() on that converts the list into a single string, complete with the characters like brackets and quotation marks inside.

```
>>> q = "hello hi there"
>>> query = q.split()
>>> q
'hello hi there'
>>> query
['hello', 'hi', 'there']
>>> str(query) == "['hello', 'hi', 'there']"
True
```

Regardless, what is it that you're ultimately trying to do?  If you're trying to split a string into a list of words, look up any of those words that exist in `D`, look at the corresponding set of numbers for each word, and finally return the intersection of all those sets, then something like this should work:

```
def find_coexistence(D, query):
    query = query.split(" ")
    sets_to_intersect = [ D[word] for word in query if word in D ]
    return set.intersection(*sets_to_intersect)
```